# MySQL/Postgres Compatible WEEKDAY/DOW

Tags: mysql, postgresql, extract, compatibility, weekday

I want a query that runs on both MySQL and Postgres without modification (I am migrating from MySQL -> Postgres and, ideally, I want to run the exact same queries on both databases while testing the migration rather than different database-specific queries).

My original MySQL query uses WEEKDAY:

```
SELECT WEEKDAY('2016-06-24');
+-----------------------+
| WEEKDAY('2016-06-24') |
+-----------------------+
|                     4 |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I know that Postgres has EXTRACT but it's not quite the same (and does not work with 'dow' on MySQL):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(dow FROM '2016-06-24'::date);
date_part 
-----------
     5
```

Is there a single function/statement/query that will run without modification on MySQL and Postgres that has the behaviour of WEEKDAY on MySQL?

I would like to avoid creating a custom function on Postgres for this behaviour.

(Actual query uses columns etc so casts shouldn't be a problem)

Comment: I doubt it. You could use `(date - known_date) % 7` if they both allowed date subtraction and the same modulus operator. But I don't think they do.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no way to avoid an user defined function:

```
create or replace function weekday (_date date)
returns integer as $$
    select extract(isodow from _date)::int - 1;
$$ language sql immutable;

select weekday('2016-06-24');
 weekday 
---------
       4
```